# ElasticSearch - multi-match with filter - returns no result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem. My search result returns zero when I add a filter in my JSON request

```
{
 "body":
   {
      "query":{
         "multi_match":
               {
              "query":"Joe Jerick Aparments",
              "fields":["name","Category","address","description"]}
       },
   "filter":
        {
           "source":"Category":"Apartments"
      }
```

}
}

First things first,

1. Yes, there is already data.
2. Yes there is no error
3. Yes there is no misspelled words

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  index: "stores",
  type: "stores",
  id: "1",
  body: {
    name: "Joe Jerick Apartments",
    Category: "Apartments"
    address: "Somewhere down the road",
    description: "Best apartment yet!"
  }
}
```

So, I didn't see this in my earlier comment but if the fields you're querying on are nested inside of body (in storage -- not in retrieval) you'll need a [nested query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) to get at the fields listed (I'm not sure if you're describing your mapping or what it looks like on query retrieval for a match_all)

If this is the case you'll need body to be mapped as "nested" and then your query would look something like this.

```
{
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "query": {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Joe Jerick Apartments",
            "fields": [
              "body.name",
              "body.Category",
              "body.address",
              "body.description"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "term": {
            "body.Category": "Apartments"
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Altertively you could re-import your records with a flattened structure

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Joe Jerick Apartments",
  "Category": "Apartments",
  "address": "Somewhere down the road",
  "description": "Best apartment yet!"
}
```

Comment: Again, Thank you for your effort. I'm having an error though  Parse Failure [No parser for element [nested]]];

Comment: I've updated the query -- I think your fields might be declared as "type":"object" which would mean you don't need the outer nested portion, but that your fields may have already been flattened but just require being prefaced with "body."

Answer (score 0):

Try this query instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Joe Jerick Apartments",
          "fields": [
             "name",
          "Category",
          "address",
          "description"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "Category": "Apartments"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I had this error: [filtered] query does not support [multi_match]];

Comment: Just fixed the nesting errors. Multi match should work your field.

Comment: Hi thank you again for the reply. There's no error this time only the problem is there is also no result. Am I missing something?

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of the index (how stuff is mapped) there's no way for me to tell. Using the query this way you'll get a match if the string "Joe Jerick Apartments" is in your index -- but it could be that part of way the field is stored is lowercased or has other things to throw it off. It's better when starting to play around with a standard dataset, for example, something like the shakespeare set http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/snippets/shakespeare.json)

Comment: Hi thanks again! Please bear with me. 
Here's my JSON format

{
index: "stores",
type: "stores",
id: "1",
body: {
name: "Joe Jerick Apartments",
Category: "Dormitory"
address: "Somewhere down the road",
description: "Best apartment yet!"
}
}

I was thinking maybe I should put a mapper or so?

Comment: looks like the filter should be "Category": "Dormitory" not "Category": "Apartments". It's filtering out that result because its not matching on the category field (while it is matching on the name)

Comment: Wait oh sorry, It was Apartments. My bad. It still give me zero results though. I'm really sorry. I hope I'm not bothering you that much...