# And operator mongoosastic (filter)

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

How can I add filter to my query to get for example just users where `role admin` ?

Here is my query:

```
userModel.search({
            "multi_match": {
                "fields": ["firstName", 'lastName', 'specialities', 'profession', 'country', 'state', 'city'],
                "query": req.query.q,
                "fuzziness": "AUTO"
            }
        },
        {
            from: (pageNum - 1) * perPage,
            size: perPage
        },
        function (err, results) {
...
```

I need to do something like this just with mognoosastic:
[ElasticSearch - multi-match with filter - returns no result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25730459/elasticsearch-multi-match-with-filter-returns-no-result)

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query Format

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": { 
      "multi_match": {
      "query": "values",
      "fields": [
        "filed_one","field_two"
       ]
       }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "field_name": {
            "gte": 1467311400,
            "lte": 1468866599
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Let me know if this format help or not

Comment: Where to put it? also I need to have `multi_match`

Comment: Edited my answer with multi_match , hope it will help you !!

Comment: I need filter for string field `role` value `doctor`, is possible to filter that?

Comment: Add value as doctor and field_one as role

Comment: Is that work fine, please mark answer as right so other also can refer this