# How to filter elastic search query

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose

This is my node.js, mongoosastic search function:

```
 exports.search = function (req, res) {
  if (!req.query.q) return res.status(400).send('No Query Provided')
  log.error(req.query.q)

  var query = {query_string: {query: req.query.q}};

  var filterDeleted = {
    term: {
      isDeleted: true
    }
  };

  User.search(query, {filter: filterDeleted}, (err, results) => {
    if (err) return handleError(res, err)
    var ret = _.map(results.hits.hits, result => ({
      userID: result._id,
      _score: result._score,
      name: result._source.name,
      loc: result._source.loc,
      info: result._source.info,
      images: result._source.images,
    }))
    return res.send(ret)
  })
}
```

By all this I want to ask elastics "give all users matching to req.query.q, whose 
isDelete property is false(which are not deleted).
Actually this does not work, and as I understand, it ignores the filter and goes forward. So it displays the deleted users too.
Please someone help me find the solution.

Comment: Can you post the generated JSON request?

Comment: sorry, but shouldn't be in code `isDeleted=false`?

Comment: Mr.  luk off course I respect your opinion, but what if I want to filter all deleted users, from being sent by response.

Comment: Although I have also  tried the other way round, again the same (doesn't work).

Comment: maybe try to nest filter **inside** of `query` body as written [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39271712/and-operator-mongoosastic-filter)

Comment: Would you please show me how to expand my query?how to add your sugestion to my existing code, and will it help me not to display deleted users.

Comment: I found the solution, but now I got another issue...

Comment: var query = {
    query_string: {
      filtered: {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: req.query.q,
          }
        },
        filter: {
          term: {
            isDeleted: false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

Comment: Now I have problem with elastics sync. when I delete user, it is still seen, until I restart the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem solved by modifying the code like this

```
exports.search = function (req, res) {

  if (!req.query.q) return res.status(400).send('No Query Provided')
  log.error(req.query.q)
  User.search({query_string: {query: req.query.q}}, (err, results) => {
    if (err) return handleError(res, err)
    var ret = _.map(results.hits.hits, result => ({
      userID: result._id,
      _score: result._score,
      name: result._source.name,
      loc: result._source.loc,
      info: result._source.info,
      images: result._source.images
    }))
    return res.send(ret)
  })
}
```